# Java use boolean for if statement and change if needed

Tags: java, android

I'm new to java and unfortunately my brain is fixed in javascript land...  This isn't good.

Anyways, I'm trying to just make a simple menu open and close using java.  I have this script:

```
public class StartPage extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_page);

        //Handlers
        RelativeLayout menuContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.MenuContainer);
        ImageView menuButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.temp_menu);
        Boolean menuOpen = false;
        //Make sure the menu is not displaying
        menuContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!menuOpen) {
                    boolean menuOpen = true;
                    RelativeLayout menuContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.MenuContainer);
                    menuContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    boolean menuOpen = false;
                    RelativeLayout menuContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.MenuContainer);
                    menuContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So, I make the variable `menuOpen` `false` right off the bat, but I want to use and manipulate that variable in an if statement.

I get an error in the if statement that says I need to make the variable final, so I make it final, but then I'm not able to change that variable later on.

This is my javascript brain thinking, so I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this in Java.  Any help?

Comment: I'm 99% sure that you don't need `if (menuOpen == false)`, you can just use `if (!menuOpen)`

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry - that's what I had before just `if(!menuOpen)`, I was playing around a lot with it just as trial and error

Comment: Don't declare menuOpen **inside** a method, as it will go out of scope as soon as the method finishes.  Try declaring it inside the class.

Comment: Yeah, keep track of your scope like @LukePark mentioned

Comment: Make `menuOpen` as member variable of the class `StartPage`. Then access it using `StartPage .this.menuOpen` inside anonymous class.

Comment: So declare the variable under `public class StartPage...`?  I've done that and it gives me the same result.  I can open the menu, but I can not close it

Comment: @Ashiquzzaman, That worked!  Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: `unfortunately my brain is fixed in javascript land... This isn't good` ...but, why???

Comment: @charliebrownie, because Java and javascript are not the same... and I don't know all the nuances in Java yet. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `menuOpen` as member variable of the class `StartPage`. Then access it using `StartPage .this.menuOpen` inside anonymous class.

```
public class StartPage extends Activity {
    boolean menuOpen = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_page);

        //Handlers
        RelativeLayout menuContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.MenuContainer);
        ImageView menuButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.temp_menu);
        //Make sure the menu is not displaying
        menuContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!StartPage.this.menuOpen) {
                    StartPage.this.menuOpen = true;
                    RelativeLayout menuContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.MenuContainer);
                    menuContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    StartPage.this.menuOpen = false;
                    RelativeLayout menuContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.MenuContainer);
                    menuContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Added my working script to your answer, will accept in 7 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Just put the menuOpen varible outside of the method.

```
public class StartPage extends Activity {

 Boolean menuOpen = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

This way the listener's class has access to it.